# How can I mock the following request: DELETE {{url}}/users/{{user_id}}

Tags: postman

It returns me an error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "name": "mockRequestNotFoundError",
        "message": "We were unable to find any matching requests for this method type and the mock path, '/users/444', in your collection."
    }
}
```

This request is a part of the bigger workflow, {{user_id}} variable has the value from previously launched request `POST /users`.

How can I resolve this problem? Any workarounds?

**EDITED**

Steps to reproduce problem:

1. Create collection "Users"
2. Add mock (automatically "url" variable is set)
3. Add POST request "Create user"
4. In "Tests" add a line `pm.environment.set("user_id", pm.response.json().id);`
5. Set url to `{{url}}/users`
6. Add example, add body content to `{"id":444}` and returned status to `200 OK`, save it
7. Save and run request, now variable `user_id` has a value `444`
8. Create DELETE request "Delete user"
9. Set url to `{{url}}/users/{{user_id}}`
10. Add example, add status `204 No Content` and save it
11. Save and run request

The returned error will be as described above. 
Variable `user_id` is known at the time of creating the mock, no error is thrown when saving.

**RESOLVED**

I thought that for some reason Postman is not creating an example mock endpoint because of returned error.
Now writing edited version of this post with steps to reproduce I've found out that I had defined key `x-mock-response-code` in request with value 200, and the defined example returns 204 - this is the cause of an error which now make sense to me.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by mocking it?

Comment: Yesterday I've just started playing with Postman, I've read an article http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/07/28/api-testing-tips-from-a-postman-professional/ and based on it I have separated workspaces for documentation and tests. 
Now I'm just thinking that the mocking is suitable for documentation purpose - where ie. frontend developers will benefit from it seeing the response.
I've tried use mocking for testing, which for now I'm pretty sure is my misunderstanding?

Comment: First of all if you write a test and it gives you such a negative result you should find the cause of this, not try to find how to work around. If it's OK that in your tests a requests returns an error then why won't you just adjust your tests and make it as an expected flow? Do you really need to mock it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article of how to mock a postman request: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/mock_servers/mocking_with_examples

Here is how to set up a mock server: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/mock_servers/setting_up_mock

And there is one more way to mock with postman: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/mock_servers/mock_with_api

But as I understood the idea here is not to mock a request, but to mock a response. So you just generate the needed response and they you make a call to a postman mock server that returns you previously generated response that you can use as you want.

But you cannot mock it in the way that you send a request to your endpoint and get a different result.

Comment: Denis, thanks for your time and help, I've resolved the problem - explanation is in my edited post.